# Spring MVC issue returns HttpStatus 302 when trying to access a page other than home page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My Spring MVC application shows a weird behavior. When a client who opens the website for the very first time but goes directly to any page other than the home page URL (for example www.xyz.com/signUp), the application returns a HttpStatus.302 and redirects it to the home page (www.xyz.com). The next time the client accesses the sign up page, it works as expected and goes to www.xyz.com/signUp.

Find below the application.xml, web.xml and spring-security.xml for my application. Please feel free to ask for any other content if required for providing a solution.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<display-name>MyApp</display-name>

<!-- Spring Security Configuration File -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlet and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/exception/404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/exception/400.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/exception/403.jsp</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/exception/commonException.jsp</location>
</error-page>



</web-app>
```

**application.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<import resource="spring-security.xml" />

<!-- <import resource="social.xml" />

<import resource="social-security.xml" /> -->

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.inw.xyz" />

<context:spring-configured />

<jpa:repositories base-package="com.inw.xyz.repository" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="noTextEncryptor" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors"
    factory-method="noOpText" />


</bean>


<bean id="usersConnectionRepository"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.jdbc.JdbcUsersConnectionRepository">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
    <constructor-arg ref="noTextEncryptor" />
</bean>

<bean id="connectionFactoryLocator"
    class="org.springframework.social.connect.support.ConnectionFactoryRegistry">
    <property name="connectionFactories">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.social.facebook.connect.FacebookConnectionFactory">

            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

    <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000000" />

</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/XYZ" />
    <property name="username" value="abc" />
    <property name="password" value="abc123" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.inw.xyz.domain" />
    <property name="jpaProperties">  
       <props>  
           <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>  
       </props>  
  </property>  
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- Tiles configuration -->

<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles/tiles-definitions.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="userRegisterationValidator" class="com.inw.xyz.validator.UserRegisterationValidator" />





<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <!-- SMTP settings -->
    <property name="host" value="mail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="25" />
    <property name="username" value="webmaster@xyz.com" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />

    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>  -->
            <prop key="mail.mime.charset">UTF-8</prop>
            <!-- <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>  -->
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="velocityEngine"
    class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">
                org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:environment.properties"/>

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http authentication-manager-ref="userAuthManager">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/home" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signUp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/signUp/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />



    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <form-login login-page='/' authentication-failure-url="/" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" logout-url="/logout" />
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            expired-url="/" />
    </session-management>
</http>

<beans:bean id="userAuthManager" class="com.inw.xyz.security.UserAuthManager">
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />  
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: When you say gets redirected to the home page do you mean to the root of the webapp `/`?

Comment: Also do you have any logging enable for the spring framework, it could be that when user first hits the server he wont have a session and then invlid session is intercepting and redirecting. then creating the users session after hence they dont get redirect next time.

Comment: Yes, I mean the root of the webapp

Comment: You have rules for anonymous access but haven't setup that correctly. Also `/*` and `/**` look a bit conflicting. Why would one level deep allow a ROLE and everything else is only for anonymous access?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> remove invalid-session-url="/" attribute in <session-management > tag in spring-security.xml try this-
>
>   <session-management>
>         <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
>             expired-url="/" />
>     </session-management>
> ```